# where do the project files go in Eclipse when you close a project?

Tags: eclipse, projects

I opened a workspace in Eclipse and it has folders for 10 different projects in the Package Explorer, but only 2 projects are open.  The other 8 are not.  I try to open the projects and it says 'Open Project' has encountered a problem.  The project description file (.project) for . . . is missing.  Where does the project information go when projects are closed in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

They go nowhere. In fact you just tell eclipse to ignore your project when you close it, no files of the project are moved. 
It is most likely that your `.project` file was corrupted or removed from your filesystem by another program after you closed your project.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the projekt in package explorer. Look at what it says under "Location". That is where Eclipse will search for a .project file.

For me the issue you describe when I have problems with a project in our versioncontrol system, and I'm not logged in properly.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this same problem and found that it was my OneDrive that was the issue. Either store the files in the C drive from Eclipse to go around the OneDrive or disable syncing to the OneDrive from the desired folder location. I spent way to much time on this I hope this saves someone else some time!